# Enable PHP 5.5 OPCache

Tags: php, caching, php-5.5, opcache

After configuring OPCache [as recomanded](http://php.net/manual/en/opcache.installation.php#opcache.installation.recommended), It's not working.

So, How to debug OPCache to see where is the problem?

Or I am missing something?

My config:

php.ini
[image]

php -v
[image]

[image]

And in code

```
opcache_get_status(); // return false
//but
extension_loaded('Zend OPcache') // return true
```

Comment: I've answered this Q 2 or 3 times on this tag. Opcache uses a SMA between processes forked from a common parent.  Since the scope of a CLI invocation is a single request, it does nothing when executed in a CLI context.  Search the previous [opcache] Qs for further details.

Comment: I didn't executed in a CLI context, it is on website via apache. But I will look at the tag, thanks!

Comment: in which case the cli `php -v` isn't relevant.  You need the the `mod_php5` version and you need to run any `opcache_*` API calls as a web request event if just a `wget` from a localhost URI to get meaningful diagnostics

Answer (score 3):

It has been quite some time so I imagine you have moved on from this issue but in case you have not.  Is noticed you are running Xdebug...

Have you checked your php.ini to make sure that the following is not an issue?

```
If you want to use OPcache with » Xdebug, you must load OPcache before Xdebug.
```

http://php.net/manual/en/opcache.installation.php

The other thing probably worth mentioning is that you do not need to specify the path to the shared library.  The following should suffice:

```
zend_extension=opcache.so
```

Answer (score 2):

I had same problem. I have edited `php.ini` file in `C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.17\bin` location and problem solved. however before I edited `php.ini` in `C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.6.15` path.
at all you should edit `php.ini` file in `C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.17\bin` path. I am enjoying speed of OPCache!