# Can't enable Zend OPCache in PHP 5.6.30

Tags: php, opcache

I'm having trouble to enable Zend OPCache in compiled PHP 5.6.30.

It was compiled using '--enable-opcache' although it's not necessary at that version.

I already added to php.ini:

```
zend_extension=path_to_opcache.so
opcache.enable=1
```

Also tried enabling opcache.error_log but didn't write anything to the specified file.

I've tried some others options, none of them showed **"Zend OPCache" *section*** at `phpinfo();`.

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: How do you know that it's *not* enabled? OpCache is quite transparent.

Comment: @Sammitch I know it should be shown in phpinfo like the [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FZrEN.png) in this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28899673/enable-php-5-5-opcache)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that my php.ini was not where it should be. I created a symbolic link to the directory specified in `phpinfo's` **Configuration File (php.ini) Path** linking my php.ini, restarted php-fpm and now OPCache is enabled.